# Prove that these matrices are similar

Tags: linear-algebra

If A is a matrix that belongs to $k^{m*n}$, B  another matrix that belongs to $k^{n*m}$

D=
\begin{pmatrix}
AB & 0 \\
B & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
L=

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
B & BA
\end{pmatrix}

Prove that these matrices in $k^{(m+n)x(m+n)}$  are similar.

Then, if m=n, AB y BA have the same Characteristic polynomial (explain it)

---

This is what I tried to do:  By definition,
D and L are similar if there is a invertible matrix C that: $D = C^{-1}. L . C$
So, $C.D = C.C^{-1}.L.C$ Then, $C.D=L.C$, so I can create a generic matrix and try to find a relation.
In this case, I can define
C = \begin{pmatrix}
E & F \\
G & H 
\end{pmatrix}
So C.D =
\begin{pmatrix}
E.AB +F.B & 0 \\
G.AB + H.B & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
On the other hand, L.C=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
B.E +BA.G & B.F+BA.H
\end{pmatrix}
So I have:

E.AB + FB = 0

G.AB + H.B = B.E + BA.G

0 = B.F +BA.H

And after that, I have to find a relation between E,F,G,H and A,B, AB,BA.

Is this the right way to solve this problem?
I'm having a bit of a hard time being able to work with matrices "inside" a matrix. I would like to know if this is the way to solve it or is there something I need to be aware of.
Then, to prove that AB and BA have the same characteristic polynomial, I was thinking of proving that both are similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$ \begin{pmatrix} I & A\\
0 &I
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\
B &BA
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} AB & ABA\\
B &BA
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$  \begin{pmatrix} AB & 0\\
B &0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} I & A\\
0 &I
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} AB & ABA\\
B &BA
\end{pmatrix}$$
Thus the matrices are similar. Hence their characteristic polynomials are equal. If $n=m$ the characteristic polynomial of $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\
B &BA
\end{pmatrix}$$
is equal to the characteristic polynomial of $BA$ times $x^m,$ while the characteristic polynomial of $$\begin{pmatrix} AB & 0\\
B &0
\end{pmatrix}$$ is equal to the characteristic polynomial of $AB$ times $x^m.$ Hence the characteristic polynomials of $AB$ and $BA$ are equal.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if you could help me to understand how did you find that matrix? or you just tried with some intuition? thanks in advance

Comment: I have started solving the problem for numbers $a$ and $b$ and $2\times 2$ matrices $$\begin{pmatrix}ab & 0 \\ b & 0\end{pmatrix},\ \ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ b & ba \end{pmatrix}$$